# Not able to filter text data in r (Using dplyr library)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset available with below field(refer **Database:** Sum2)  and I want to apply the filter on Column "var"

**Database:** Sum2

```
       IID var             Data
 1     993 A             804584
 2     993 G             455158
 3     993 A          640008724 
 4     993 M          900007602 
 5     993 T              40415
 6     993 R                884
 7     993 T              -1752
 8     993 R               1950
++++ More 5k field
```

Below is the code for remove "A" and "M" data from the above table

```
library(dplyr)
noscope = c("A", "M")
sum2 %>% select(IID ,var ,Data) %>% Filter(var != noscope)
```

after running above code received below error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I have also tried as.character() on "var" column but still, it's not working for me.

Did I miss something on the above code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `%in%` and `filter` instead of `Filter`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Sum2 %>% 
    select(IID, var, Data) %>% 
    filter(!var %in% noscope)
#  IID var   Data
#1 993   G 455158
#2 993   T  40415
#3 993   R    884
#4 993   T  -1752
#5 993   R   1950
```

NOTE: `Filter` is a `base R` function and the parameters passed are different for that.  Regarding the `!=`, it works when we are comparing with a single string character.  Here, there are more than one, so we check with `%in%` and later negate (`!`)

#### data

```
Sum2 <- structure(list(IID = c(993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 993L, 
993L), var = c("A", "G", "A", "M", "T", "R", "T", "R"), Data = c(804584L, 
 455158L, 640008724L, 900007602L, 40415L, 884L, -1752L, 1950L)),
class =  "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: @Ghanshyam  I copied the data based on what you showed in the post and it is working fine for me

Comment: @Ghanshyam `R` is case sensitive `Sum2` and `sum2` are different

Comment: Thanks for the quick support. The issue was "Filter". actually, that should be "filter"